# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cycle' of undefined

Tags: javascript

HTML Code:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-popular-devices" data-slide-to="0" class="pip"></li>             
                <li data-target="#carousel-popular-devices" data-slide-to="1" class="pip"></li>                 
                <li data-target="#carousel-popular-devices" data-slide-to="2" class="pip active"></li>                  
                <li class="all">
                        <a href="3" class="all">blabla</a>
                </li>   
</ol>
```

and this is the part of the javascript :

```
var $this = $(this), href
  , $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) //strip for ie7
  , options = $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())
  , slideIndex

$target.carousel(options)

if (slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')) {
  $target.data('carousel').pause().to(slideIndex).cycle()
}

e.preventDefault()
```

and i am getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cycle' of undefined** on

> $target.data('carousel').pause().to(slideIndex).cycle()

this line.

I've just started to use js and if its a trivial question, sorry for that.

thanks advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the code you posted, uses an external library called "jQuery"

its a Javascript file with lots of extension methods and other goodies. you probably didnt link it to your page.

you need to link jquery before all other scripts:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

or if you dont want to depend on external links, you can download this library to your website and use it locally. download jquery from [HERE](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: You also need some additional library for carousel, which is not part of core jQuery. See documentation for where you got your example, if it's jCarousel or sth else.

Comment: @KristjanVeskimäe yes exactly. i would recommend to start with basic tutorials first, a good place to start would be [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) even though it has some errors, it is a good place to learn the basics

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning value to slideIndex instead of comparison.
Instead of this.

```
if (slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')) {
    $target.data('carousel').pause().to(slideIndex).cycle()
}
```

use this:

```
if (slideIndex == $this.attr('data-slide-to')) {
    $target.data('carousel').pause().to(slideIndex).cycle()
}
```

Comment: the error he receives means that the object returned from `$target.data('carousel').pause().to(slideIndex)` is null.

Comment: It's because of the assigning like i said. It's not missing jQuery include. If that was the case the error would of occur on first usage of `$` jQuery sign at `$(this)`. So you're answer is wrong.

Comment: most likely we are both wrong, as the error occurs when he tries to use carousel which needs another library...

Comment: But `pause().to(slideIndex)` call works. I used carousel library before this error happens mostly because of wrong usage.

Comment: Hmm you might be right. Need to wait for op to check this out.

Comment: you both are wrong, first assigning the slideIndex then make the comparison at the same line. and @Banana youre more wrong,cause its not just about including jQuery, not that simple.

Comment: could you reproduce the error in a fiddle so we could tinker with it?

Comment: thanks but i figured it out, its happened because of a class name, i just forgot a space